# How to add tomcat-users to webapp in azure

Tags: azure, web-applications, web-config, tomcat8

I have a native Tomcat 8.5 PaaS deployed from Azure. This is not from the marketplace,  but rather straight from the Azure web application.

I need to modify the tomcat-users.xml to add a new user. Since I am using PaaS, Azure does not make this directory/file available for me to modify.

In similar situations with other web app options, I have used a web.config file in my webapps folder to specify things like jvm environment variables, etc. Is there a similar process for adding tomcat-users?

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Web Apps/Azure App Service, you can access the directory/file via the KUDU/SCM tool.

You can access the tool by visiting the address `https://<your-web-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/`.

Alternatively, from the Azure Portal, you can select the `Advanced Tools` section for the app service

[image]

KUDU/SCM site is a secure site and requires use of the same Microsoft/Azure AD account used to access the Azure portal.

Once you are on the KUDU/SCM, you can select the `Debug Console` tab and launch a powershell or command prompt. This will give you ability to access any relevant directory or file and edit them.

Comment: I can't do this. I'm using the Azure built-in web app Tomcat. I don't have write access to directories outside my own directories.

Comment: When I try to edit the tomcat-users.xml file I get "Error - 409 Conflict: Could not write to local resource 'D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\conf\tomcat-users.xml' due to error 'Access to the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\conf\tomcat-users.xml' is denied.

Comment: Ah! Apparently, you cannot access the Tomcat Manager in default install. Please see response by Prasad Kerhalkar (author) in the comments thread [in this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/09/18/accessing-the-tomcat-manager-console-on-azure-java-webapp/).